# I can't access the Mac App Store, iTunes, or Software Update on Lion

Tags: macos, network, software-update

I updated from Snow Leopard 10.6.8 to Lion. The OS update process was all right.

I can access the Internet by Firefox, but Safari.
I think my network is all right.

So, I can access the internet from Lion, but I can’t use the Mac App Store, the iTunes Store or update my system.

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: What happens if you go to the App Store?

Comment: it does not have any error information, it stands in loading all the time, but the progress bar does not running.

Comment: I found a error report about the app store:

Comment: Yes ... do tell! Was it perchance "No GUID is available. Contact Support for assistance." in red font. I had that on my hackintosh, I deleted my .plist file in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist

Comment: Do you still need assistance? What did the error report tell you? Have you tried another App Store account to make sure it's not a problem on the servers?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running an actual Mac or are you running a Hackintosh?

This is a known Hackintosh issue
http://tonymacx86.com/viewtopic.php?f=135&t=23153&start=120